# NetSuite Error: CustomFieldRef is an abstract type and cannot be instantiated

Tags: python, wsdl, netsuite

I am working on NetSuite WSDL. I am stuck on this error from past two days. I have searched on the internet but couldn't find a solution.

I try to add a [custom field](http://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_1/schema/other/customfieldlist.html?mode=package) in NetSuite using Python but I am getting the error

```
zeep.exceptions.Fault: org.xml.sax.SAXException: {urn:core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}CustomFieldRef is an abstract type and cannot be instantiated
```

Any kind of help would be appretiated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the question by using [SelectCustomFieldRef](http://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_1/schema/other/selectcustomfieldref.html?mode=package) instead of CustomFieldRef. i.e.

```
new_record['companyName']= 'test_clinic1'
new_record['firstName']= 'test_clinic_first_name1'
new_record['altName']= 'test_clinic1'
new_record['lastName']='test_last__clinic_name2'
record = RecordRef(internalId=1, type='subsidiary')
new_record['subsidiary'] = record

customField= SelectCustomFieldRef()
customField.internalId='285'
customField.scriptId='custentity_profile_type'
customField.value={
                'name': 'Clinic',
                'internalId': '2',
                'externalId': None,
                'typeId': '31'
            }

new_record['customFieldList']=CustomFieldList(customField)
```

Comment: Just to complete your answer, if the custom field is a String we need to use StringCustomFieldRef instead of SelectCustomFieldRef. Thanks for your question/answer that helped !

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty much self-explanatory though not helpful unless you already understand it.

If you want to edit/create custom field you have to instantiate the correct type.

e.g. in Java

```
StringCustomFieldRef strCF = new StringCustomFieldRef();
strCF.setInternalId(cfNSKey);
```

You can get a list of types in the [Netsuite docs](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_n3458179.html)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give a sample code in python.

Comment: It would be but I have no idea. The basic concept is that you need to create a concrete type. Java was offered because that is what I have.

Comment: Can you provide the link for sandbox NetSuite?

Comment: Your explanation is just as short as the error itself, and that link requires a login. Can you provide a summary of the relevant info?

Comment: I cannot. If you don't have a Netsuite login the info is protected by NDA/License agreements etc. Though my answer is exactly the same as the OP's self answer -- that is to use a concrete type that corresponds to the field type you are trying to access.